# Binding to a nested property in template

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I want to create a button with loading indicator for async methods, like this:

[image]

I create an `AsyncCommand` implementing `ICommand` and `INotifyPropertyChanged`(more details in MSDN Magazine April, 2014).

My `AsyncCommand` has `Execution` property and it has `IsNotCompleated` property. I want to set `Visibility` property of loader indincator using `IsNotCompleted` property.

I create UserControl inherits the `Button` and set style for this. I try to bind visibility to Button's `Command` dependency property.

There the part of `ControlTemplate` with "Loading indicator" (I use content, not Visibility, just for example)

```
 <Label HorizontalAlignment="Center"
        VerticalAlignment="Center"
        Grid.Column="1"
        Content="{Binding Command.Execution.IsNotCompleted}"/>
```

And nothing happens. If i use `TemplateBinding` instead of `Binding` I'll get compile errors:

- Nested types not supported: Command.Execution
- Unable to find type `Command.Execution`

What is the correct way to do this?

Comment: Try `Content="{Binding Command.Execution.IsNotCompleted, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"`

Comment: You say you want to bind Visbility, but you seem to be binding a presumably boolean IsNotCompleted to Content, is that intended?

Comment: @stijn, think he's just binding it to content just to get the binding work at all (so will just display true/false) for easier debugging, once he can bind to it he can just throw it at a BooleanToVisibilityConverter.

Comment: @Clemens Is there a reason why you have to use RelativeSource instead of TemplateBinding?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is using `RelativeSource.TemplatedParent`

```
<Label HorizontalAlignment="Center"
    VerticalAlignment="Center"
    Grid.Column="1"
    Content="{Binding Command.Execution.IsNotCompleted, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"/>
```